Mingw64 Environment mess
I have Ming64 installed for quite some time and every time I need to install something new like a devel package, pacman presents me a handful of options for different environments (mingw64, ucrt64, clang64, msys...)
Depending on what I need, these packages may not be available in the one or another environment, or it can be but still there are mixes and this leads the system to an inconsistent state.
How could I force mingw/pacman to prioritize a given environment (e.g., ucrt64)?

It looks like you're referring to MSYS2.
MSYS2 has different .exe files to start up specific environments:

mingw32.exe - GCC compiler targeting Intel/AMD 32-bit
mingw64.exe - GCC compiler targeting Intel/AMD 64-bit
clang32.exe - LLVM/Clang compiler targeting Intel/AMD 32-bit
clang64.exe - LLVM/Clang compiler targeting Intel/AMD 64-bit
clangarm64.exe - LLVM/Clang compiler targeting ARM 64-bit
msys2.exe - only use this when building specifically for the MSYS2 environment

As far as pacman goes, you can specify per package for which environment you want to install, for example mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-boost will install boost for LLVM/Clang targeting Intel/AMD 64-bit.
